# SharePoint Online : Create workflow via SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I tried to create **SharePoint Online** workflow using **SharePoint Designer 2010**.
After I choose "Create List Workflow", nothing happens. And my workflow doesn't get created.

Does the SharePoint Designer 2010 not support creation of workflow for SharePoint Online? Or is there anything that I should do to make it work? I have cleared the cache.

Comment: Could you tried with SharePoint Designer 2013?

Comment: @MarkL Should I use SP Designer 2013? because I am restricted to installing a new software, and existing SP Designer that already installed is 2010 version. I thought that I can use this version to create workflow in SharePoint Online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Does the SharePoint Designer 2010 not support creation of workflow for SharePoint Online?**

Based on this official [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2794961) from Microsoft you will face more issue like

- SharePoint Designer cannot display the item.
- The list of workflow actions on the server references an assembly that does not exist. Some actions will not be available.
- Microsoft SharePoint Designer cannot be used to edit web sites on servers different from SharePoint Server 2010.

So to resolve these issues, [install SharePoint Designer 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491).

**Note:** You can install SharePoint Designer 2013 alongside SharePoint Designer 2010. However, it's recommended that you **uninstall** SharePoint Designer 2010 before you install SharePoint Designer 2013.

Ref : [Workflow problems after you connect to a SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server 2013 site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2794961)

**is there anything that I should do to make it work?**

I didn't try that but this article introduces a workaround to [How to Use SharePoint Designer 2010 to Edit SharePoint 2013 Sites Successfully](https://blog.zubairalexander.com/how-to-use-sharepoint-designer-2010-to-edit-sharepoint-2013-sites-successfully/) by

- Looking for the update `KB2553382` in the SharePoint Designer 2010 section at Windows update on **your PC**.
- Highlight it and click Uninstall.