# SharePoint Online : Cannot Create Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

Because I haven't get the answer yet in this question : [SharePoint Online : Create workflow via SharePoint Designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193738/sharepoint-online-create-workflow-via-sharepoint-designer), so I tried to create workflow from list settings in SharePoint Online.
I create three-state workflow for example. I have inserted all required data, but when i wanted to save it, the OK button is disabled.

Do I need to activate some feature so I can create a new workflow from SharePoint site? Or am I do something wrong?

Note : I am not using SharePoint Designer, because I have no SharePoint Designer 2013 (as question's URL that I give above) and I don't want to use third-party add-ins or apps.

Comment: Here is the in-depth article about three state WF..Please take a look https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-Three-state-workflow-11b6c5ea-572d-4aa5-8004-59d393b7229b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bm3

Comment: @VishalMPatil yes, i have read that. Until the end of 'Add a Three-state workflow to a list' section, to click OK, the OK button is disabled

Comment: I personally recommend you to install SharePoint Designer Tool.. It is a free tool from Microsoft, it can be helpful for you to customize your SharePoint Online look and feel. SP designer will be a easy way to create workflow. Just try it..

Comment: @Aravindh90 yeah, I've ever used SharePoint Designer before. But I have a 2010 version, and it looks like I can't create a SharePoint Online Workflow using this version (as URL that I given above). So I tried using SharePoint feature to create workflow

Answer (score 0):

It seems that '`Workflows`' feature is disabled and that's why your OK butoon is greyed out. So you have to activate it.

1. Go to site settings.
2. Site collection features
3. Find and Activate '`Workflows`' feature.

[image]

This feature will offer Aggregated set of out-of-box workflows provided by SharePoint.

Also,

Make sure that you having sufficient permissions to add workflow. You must have the `Manage Lists permission` to add a workflow to a list, library, or content type. In most cases, site administrators or individuals who manage specific lists or libraries perform this task.

Comment: The 'Workflows' feature is already active, also 'Three-State Workflow' feature

Comment: Make sure that you having sufficient permissions to add workflow. You must have the Manage Lists permission to add a workflow to a list, library, or content type. In most cases, site administrators or individuals who manage specific lists or libraries perform this task.